# Spectral norm bound for difference of inverse matrices [modified]

Tags: inequality, matrix-calculus

if A is positive semidefinite and B,C are positive definite matrices, can you bound the spectral norm 
$\lVert B(I+AB)^{-1}AC - B(I+AC)^{-1}AC\rVert $ by something like $\lVert B\rVert  \lVert B - C\rVert \lVert C\rVert$?

So I guess the way to do it is 
$(I+AB)^{-1}- (I+AC)^{-1}=(I+AB)^{-1}(I+AB-I-AC)(I+AC)^{-1}$ 
and bound this ?